# Is there a way to know to which revit linked file belongs an element in forge viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am importing revit files with links on forge viewer.
I use either zip upload or model derivatve POST references to create it.

I would like to filter elements on the scene by which link (or main file) it belongs to.

I dig into code to search this info, but not found something yet.

Is there any way?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach that you could implement right away and that adds no overhead to the RVT or Forge model is to maintain your own side database mapping each Revit `UniqueId` to the RVT document containing it, and use that to answer your question. The `UniqueId` is also available in the Forge viewer, so you can use that as a key to determine the source RVT.

Another yet simpler but much heavier immediate solution would be to add the RVT document in a shared parameter to each element, so that this property also becomes  available in the Forge viewer.

Comment: What is Revit UniqueId you mention?
Is it externalId we can get from viewer.getProperties ?
If so, externalId has following format: "e1d4bdfb-2688-47c1-a386-3b48116e5fd2-0008c06b".
e1d4bdfb-2688-47c1-a386-3b48116e5fd2 refers to revit file / 
0008c06b refers to element in the model of the revit file.

 1-Is this the kind of mapping you suggest?

 2-Where do you think to store the RVT document in a shared parameter?
Thank you

Comment: 1. UniqueId is a property on each Revit elelemt: https://apidocs.co/apps/revit/2019/f9a9cb77-6913-6d41-ecf5-4398a24e8ff8.htm, and it is converted to the externalId in the Forge viewer. Using a Revit add-in, you could simply create a list of each UniqueId in each Revit RVT. Then you could determine the RVT from the externalId.

Comment: 2. add a string-valued shared parameter to each element named 'RvtDocumentName'. Store the RVT filename there. The parameter value will be translated with the model and available in the Forge viewer.

Comment: Ok, so you suggest to use add-in to prepare info into revit file. My initial idea was to not modify the revit file at all, but indeed there is not enough info if we do not provide them initially. Thanks for info.